# ObjC how to pop back to RootViewController when TabBarItem is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I got the following flow

**At Home Tab Select Evening called `[self.parentViewController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];` to Go to Class Tab**

[image: At Home Select Evening]

**At Class Tab select any Class**

[image: At Class select a class]

**Go to the next VC**

[image: Next VC]

**Select Home Again and Evening Again**

[image: Select Home and select Evening Again]

**Remain at the previous VC did not go back to RootView**
[image: Remain At the next VC]

**Should be here**
[image: ShouldBe RootViewController]

From `Home Tab` i perform a `[self.parentViewController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];` to `Class Tab`. Then from Class Tab which is embedded in `NavigationController` I will then use `seague` to go to next VC and onwards.

But when I select the `Home Tab` again I want the `Class Tab` to go back to `RootViewController`

I have tried the following but it is not working. It will just keep popping to the `RootViewController` every time the next `VC` Disappear.

```
   -(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

       [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

       [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
   }
```

I have the following code MyTabBarController which was given to me by a kind stack overflow guru but not sure where to tweak to Go back to RootViewController  Class.m tab every time new `TabBarController` is selected. Please help.

```
 - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSLog(@"didSelectViewController... ");

//==== Tried this but not triggering =====    
//[(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
//if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
    //[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
//}
//==========================================

    NSLog(@"controller class: %@", NSStringFromClass([viewController class]));
    NSLog(@"controller title: %@", viewController.title);

    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {

        // we're expecting a nav controller so cast it to a nav here
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)viewController;

        // now grab the first view controller from that nav controller
        UIViewController *firstViewControllerInNav = navController.viewControllers.firstObject;

        // check to make sure it's what we're expecting (ParentViewController)

       if ([firstViewControllerInNav isKindOfClass:[ParentViewController class]]) {
            // cast it to our parent view controller class
            [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
            ParentViewController *viewControllerToCallMethodOnAfterSelection = (ParentViewController *)firstViewControllerInNav;
            [viewControllerToCallMethodOnAfterSelection doStuffWhenTabBarControllerSelects];
        }else{
        //=== The following code will make viewWillAppear load on each tab bar item
        //=== Without it, tapping on new tab bar item will not load viewWillAppear
            [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        }
    }


}
```

**Added the following code, it does fire but doesn't bring selectedIndex = 2 back to Root**

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSUInteger shouldSelectIndex = [tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    //Check if current index is Class tab and new index is Home
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2 && shouldSelectIndex == 0) {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        //[(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        //[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:tabBarController.selectedIndex];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

**Added StoryBoard**

[image: Story Board]

**Added File Structure**

[image: File Structure]

Comment: Have you tried `viewController.navigationController`? Not sure how you arranged your storyboard but it should work if each tab have it's own navigationController as root

Comment: Yes each tab has it's own Navigation Controller where to put the `viewController.navigationController`?

Comment: Ah I thought that your code was not working, it works but it goes back everytime you tap new tab is that it? So what you exactly need is that you want to each time user tab other tab than the `Class` tab then the `Class` tab should goes back to root?

Comment: At `Home Tab`, I will click `buttonEvening` and it will execute `[self.parentViewController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2]` and take me to `Class Tab` When I will click on the link on `ClassVC` it will perform `segue` to another `VC1`. When I click Home tab. I want `VC1` to go back to `ClassVC or RootView`. If not when I click `buttonEvening` again at `HomeTab` instead of `ClassVC or RootView` I will go to `VC1`. My idea is when `HomeTab` is selected can I call `VC1` back to `ClassVC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method in your tabbarController and call this method when ever you want the class tab to get to its root view controller

```
-(void)popToClassRootViewController{
    // Considering the fact that class view contorller will always be on 3 no and will be of UINavigationController
    UINavigationController *classNavController = (UINavigationController *)[self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
    // You can get the navigation controller reference by any way you prefer
    [classNavController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:false];
}
```

In Your case i think you want to to reset the view controller whenever other tab is clicked so you can use the tabbar delegate method to check if other tabbar bar items are clicked and call that method

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSUInteger index = [tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    if (index != 2) {
       //Note: Call this method according to your need in this case it will be called whenever user will select tab other then Class
       [self popToClassRootViewController];
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then you want to goes back to root view if current tab is `Class` and `Home` tab got selected. Maybe this would be better than using `didSelectViewController`:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    NSUInteger shouldSelectIndex = [tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
    //Check if current index is Class tab and new index is Home
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 2 && shouldSelectIndex == 0) {
       //Pop to root code with `[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:tabBarController.selectedIndex]` (Class tab's navigation controller)
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, do i need to add a delegate? And call something like 'self.delegate = self'?

Comment: It's tabbarController's delegate function so yes if you meant self = tabbarController or replace `didSelectViewController ` with this one

Answer (score 0):

Clear navigation bar controller array by using below swift code

**guard let child = self.childNavController else {return}**

**child.viewControllers = []**

you can user same in objective C in tabbar didselect method

Comment: Sorry I am quite a noob. Could you please elaborate a bit more please

Comment: How to get the tabBarController at index 2 go to root. At Index 0, I have already done so. Basically, from index 2 back to index 0, how to make index2 pop to root, before switching to index 0.

Comment: NSMutableArray *tbViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
[tbViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex:2];
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:tbViewControllers];